# how to get details about an "Environment call from M-mode" exception for ecall handler?

Tags: exception, assembly, riscv, interrupt-handling, riscv32

we are integrating a new core (from pulpino to cv32).
I have no issues compiling and running code on my target, **except when calling `time()` or `srand()` or `rand()` (but not `div()` for instance),** where the default exception handler is called back and I have the following CSR values:

```
mcause : 0x0000000b
mstatus : 0x00001880 (mstatus.MPP : 03, mstatus.MIE : 01)
mepc : 0x00003476
mtval : 0x00000000
mip : 0x00000000
mie : 0xffff0000
misa : 0x40101104
```

I compiled and ran a very simple test (which is just/only a call to `rand()` that triggers the exception)
and then I display the CSR in the default exception handler with printfs.

as you can see, mcause = 0xB which is "Environment call from M-mode" ([see](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/%7Ekrste/papers/riscv-priv-spec-1.7.pdf) p29)

> The ECALL instruction is used to make a request to a higher privilege level. The binary interface
> to the execution environment will define how parameters for the request are passed, but usually
> these will be in defined locations in the integer register file. Executing an ECALL instruction causes
> an Environment Call exception.

What I understand that `ecall` is used to call for instance linux.
and by disassembling the binary, I found that `ecall` was called in the `time` and `rand` functions, but not the `div`.
This proves that the `ecall` is triggering the exception.

1/ What could explain that ecall triggers an exception?

> Executing an ECALL instruction causes
> an Environment Call exception.

OK, so I guess I should be handling the ecall exception, but how?

here is my crt0.S:

```
 .section .vectors, "ax"
  .option norvc;
  .global intvec
intvec:
  .org 0x00
  jal x0, default_exception_handler_c
  [...]

  .org 0x88
  jal x0, ecall_insn_handler
```

2/ Why the ecall triggers the `default_exception_handler_c` and not the `ecall_insn_handler`? bad hw wiring?

---

---

details:

I am working with the riscv COREV toolchain configured with:

```
riscv32-corev-elf-gcc -v
[...]
Target: riscv32-corev-elf
Configured with: ../../gcc/configure --target=riscv32-corev-elf --prefix=/build/workspace/corev-gcc-centos7/install --with-sysroot=/build/workspace/corev-gcc-centos7/install/riscv32-corev-elf --with-native-system-header-dir=/include --with-newlib --disable-shared --enable-languages=c,c++ --enable-tls --disable-werror --disable-libmudflap --disable-libssp --disable-quadmath --disable-libgomp --disable-nls --enable-multilib --with-arch=rv32imac --with-abi=ilp32 --with-bugurl=''\''https://www.embecosm.com'\''' --with-pkgversion=''\''corev-openhw-gcc-centos7-20200913'\'''
Thread model: single
Supported LTO compression algorithms: zlib
gcc version 11.0.0 20200813 (experimental) ('corev-openhw-gcc-centos7-20200913')
```

compilation flags include:

```
-Os -Wa,-march=rv32ic -Wall -Wdouble-promotion -Wextra -Wformat=2 -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -fno-builtin -fno-builtin-printf -fno-merge-all-constants -g0 -march=rv32ic -s -std=gnu11
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What could explain that ecall triggers an exception?

I am a bit confused by this question. ECALL is *documented* to trigger an exception, indeed that is the *purpose* of that operation, akin to SYSENTER / SYSCALL on x86/x64.

The idea here is to facilitate a [context switch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context_switch). Functions like `div()` can be resolved in unpriviledged mode, others like `time()` cannot (for example, because unpriviledged mode does not allow access to the system clock). So their implementation sets certain registers in a certain way ("please give me the clock's status"), and then triggers an exception (ECALL). The exception handler -- which runs at a higher priviledge level -- checks the value of those registers, which tell it which functionality was required by the caller. The functionality is performed, results are stored in registers, and control is returned to the (unpriviledged) caller.

> Why the ecall triggers the default_exception_handler_c and not the ecall_insn_handler? bad hw wiring?

I very much doubt that, because it is elementary functionality. It is much more likely that your exception handling is incorrectly implemented.

Comment: thank you.
"Executing an ECALL instruction causes an Environment Call exception." 
"OK, so I guess I should be handling the ecall exception, but how?"
I understood that ecall triggers an exception and that the exception shall be handled, but i'm not sure how, indeed, to handle this exception. This is what the first part of my question is about.

Comment: Furthermore, I don't understand when you say " It is much more likely that your exception handling is incorrectly implemented.".
In fact, the handling is incorrectly implemented, of course, there is no handling yet. But that is not what triggers it. I don't know how to make the ecall triggering the `ecall_insn_handler` (0x88) instead of the `default_exception_handler_c` (0x00). That was the second part of the question.

Comment: @GuillaumeD I am glad to see that you feel my answer helped you. Sorry for not replying to your comments; I was really at a loss on how I could explain it better.